# System proxy settings not taking effect on Kali (debian 6)

Tags: networking, gnome, kali-linux, socks, tor

I'm in the process of trying to configure TOR on a Kali installation, as a system-wide SOCKS proxy. I just did this successfully on Ubuntu, and it worked like a charm. I installed TOR & Vidalia from the Debian repositories, started the TOR service using `service tor start`, and checked to see that my computer was listening on the default port, `9050`, for SOCKS connections to be routed through the TOR service; which it was. Vidalia tells me I'm connected to the TOR network.

The problem is the Network -> Proxy section of the settings manager in Kali. I can enter in the necessary information to connect to the local SOCKS proxy, but there is no 'apply' button or anything to that effect. I have entered the information, hit enter, exited out (and when I go back, it is still there) of the settings manager, restarted the `networking` service, etc., but I have not been able to get the proxy settings to take effect. This worked beautifully in Ubuntu, I entered the SOCKS settings in the settings manager and hit 'apply', and all traffic was being routed through the TOR network. Any ideas?